# Get image quality in Java in the same way as ImageMagick's "identify" command

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, jpeg, image-compression

I am trying to get the quality of an image using Java and I am having a hard time to find any API that would do that.

I stumbled upon the ImageMagick command [`identify`](https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) which works great but I would like to know if there is a Java API that would do something similar.

[Here is ImageMagick command that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378080/1529274)

How can I get the quality of an image using Java?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Looking at the question, it doesn't look like it's specifically a library request, but rather a request to solve a problem using Java (which may or may not need an external library to solve). I updated the title to make this more clear.   This question seems to completely OK based on this explanation of how to avoid asking a "recommendation" question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254394/1108305.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The ImageMagick website](https://imagemagick.org/script/develop.php) has a page that lists APIs for numerous programming languages, including Java.  These can be used to get the quality from within a Java program.

The two listed Java libraries are [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/) and [Im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/):

> [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/) provides an object-oriented Java interface to ImageMagick. [Im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) is a pure-java interface to the ImageMagick command-line.

Note that the JMagick link appears to be broken.  A web search suggests that the [htechblue/jmagick](https://github.com/techblue/jmagick) fork on GitHub is a more recently maintained replacement.

Either of these libraries should work for accessing the quality from within a Java program.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the compression of an image you can compare the actual file size to the size you'd get if you were storing the image "raw".

For example a jpeg file that's 1024x1024, true color (24bpp) that's 384Kb you'd get a ratio of (384x1024) / (1024x1024x3) = 0.125, this means the jpeg produced a file that's 12% of raw image.

No need to uncompress the image.

Comment: You forgot to delete the answer of your over account before copying the text?