# How to use ImageMagick command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, image, imagemagick, jpeg

My goal is to determine the compression parameters of the jpeg image that I have. As I understood from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024947/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-quality-level-of-a-jpeg/18378080#18378080), it's possible using the ImageMagick function *identity*. I downloaded from the official site and installed **ImageMagick-7.0.2-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe**. Now, I have an application with GUI called ImageMagick Display that seems useless. Where can I find an IM command line to type this:

```
identify -format '%Q' yourimage.jpg
```

Comment: `Start`->`All programs`->`Accessories`->`Command Prompt`. Then type `magick identify -format %Q SomeFile.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sadly, 'magick' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch

Comment: If you didn't add the directory where you installed ImageMagick to your PATH, Windows won't be able to find it. You have 2 choices. 1) Use the full path every time you run ImageMagick, i.e. something like `"C:\Programs\Image Magick\convert"` or 2) Go to `Settings`->`System`->`Advanced`->`Environment Variables` and click `Edit` and add the directory in to the start of your PATH.

Comment: Put `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick` (or wherever you installed it) in your environment variable path (should have already occured during installation) and use `magick identify` not `identify`. Any command name you want to use put `magick` before it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since it is version 7.x, there is a checkbox at the time of installation that says '*Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)*'.  You need to select that checkbox during installation.

Screenshot: [image]

Once done, you will be able to use the commands from command line.

Another option is to use the command `magick identify --version`

For version 6.x, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Open cmd>give access to your path in cmd then hit Enter.
Now type `magick identify "D:\your path\name of file"` then hit Enter,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Type it into the command prompt; alternatively you could put it into a batch file and drop your image over the batch file icon. But in both cases you would then need to think of a way to display the result.

Comment: Also you could redirect the output to file `identify -format '%Q' yourimage.jpg > output.txt` and read it in notepad. Or even redirect output to clipboard `identify -format '%Q' yourimage.jpg | clip` and paste it in your favorite text editor.

Comment: @rostok, `'identify' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch` as expected

Comment: Did you allow Imagemagick to add the path to environmental variables on install? This identify -format '%Q' E:\Pictures\_MG_5189.jpg > E:\Pictures\output.txt gives me an output of '99' in the text file although I am using 6.9.3. "as expected" sounds a bit pompus; if you do not like Imagemagick find something else?

Comment: "Did you allow Imagemagick to add the path to environmental variables on install?" Hmm.. I didn't forbid. Can I do it manually? "as expected" means that I expected that, since I had already tried.

Comment: @Glinka See comment (to original question) by Mark Setchell - concerning adding to environmental variable Path. But be careful about how you do it because if you spoil it some of your other software may fail to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from command line

type `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe" identify -format '%Q' yourimage.jpg`

replace `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe"` with your directory that has `ImageMagick-...\magick.exe` installed, and place double quotes at the start of `"C:\....` and at the end `...magick.exe"`,

Answer (score 1):

Hope ImageMagick is installed in location C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16

If you are using Imagemagick version above 7.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16>magick.exe compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\Service\Test\636753876766621882_cropped_test_1.jpg" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\Service\Test\crpd_ref_test_.jpg" null:-

1227.74 (0.0187342) @ 50,50 => output

For image magick below 7.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16>compare.exe -metric RMSE -subimage-search "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\Service\Test\636753876766621882_cropped_test_1.jpg" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\Service\Test\crpd_ref_test_.jpg" null:-

1227.74 (0.0187342) @ 50,50 => output

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use zsh to call the command line on windows, just add:

```
export magick=/path/to/exe 
Eg. export magick=/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/magick.exe
```