# How to get the compression of an image

Tags: python, compression

I am trying to get the compression rate of two images in Error Level Analysis form. One image is manipulated and the other is not.

I want to get the compression level to use it as a split feature in random forests. If the compression is high then it is manipulated.

Here is the manipulated image in ELA

[image: manipulated image in ELA]

Here is the non-manipulated image in ELA

[image: non-manipulated image in ELA]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid asking multiple questions. Rather post them separate,

Comment: This should answer your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024947/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-quality-level-of-a-jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024947/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-quality-level-of-a-jpeg)